# What's wrong with this snippet of shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

Tags: android, android-webview, facebook-android-sdk, webviewclient

I want my app let it open in facebook app or twitter app or mail client. I know I'm very close to my answer. Please Help.

This is my snippet...

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;



import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("example.com")) {
        return false;
    }  if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("facebook.com")
|| Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("twitter.com")
|| Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("mail@example.com")) {
        return true;
    }if(url.startsWith("Call / WhatsApp :")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }


}
```